# How to transpose a table in expl3

Tags: tex-core, expl3, xparse

I've been very impressed with [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3), and have written a wonderful document command using `\ProcessList` that takes a comma separated list and turns it into a (basically) 1 column table.

```
\stacky{A,B,C,D}
-> \begin{tabular}{rr}
   \tiny 1st & A \\
   \tiny 2nd & B \\
   \tiny 3rd & C \\
   \tiny 4th & D
   \end{tabular}
```

Now I've become mad with the power and want to specify more than one column at a time. Something like:

```
\stacksy{ 5: A,B,C,D ; 6: A,C,D,B ; 3: C,A,B,D }
-> \begin{tabular}{rrrr}
             & 5 & 6 & 3 \\ \hline
   \tiny 1st & A & A & C \\
   \tiny 2nd & B & C & A \\
   \tiny 3rd & C & D & B \\
   \tiny 4th & D & B & D \\
   \end{tabular}
```

Everything is fine, except that the input is in column-major order, but TeX (or the tabular environment) expects row-major order.

**How do I transpose the input list of lists?**

Comment: Not an answer, but it's important to note that `xparse` is about 'parsing' in the sense 'reading LaTeX2e command syntax' rather than 'parsing arbitrary input'.

Comment: @JosephWright: Does it sound right that I should be using the sequence splits and maps from `expl3` instead of ProcessList from `xparse`? Scott's solution is working very well, and I'll likely rewrite my single-stack version to use those ideas.

Comment: No, as what you are doing is defining an input syntax. I'm simply flagging up that `\ProcessList` and the like can only take you so far: we've been asked before about _extremely_ complex input, which is really beyond the scope of `xparse`. Currently, so are nested lists (indeed, I'd have to think hard about a suitable syntax!).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a method that will produce a rectangular array of numbers that are given as columns.

- The syntax is `stacksys{col 1;col 2;...;col n}` where `col i` is the ith column with entries given as a comma separated list.
- I fiddled with the input a bit to show how column and row headings can be introduced.
- `array` can be changed to `tabular` if that is desired.
- `\stacksys{,r1,r2;c1,1,2;c2,3,4;c3,5,6}` produces:

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_ss_num_cols_int
\int_new:N \l_ss_num_rows_int
\bool_new:N \l_has_run_bool

\NewDocumentCommand{\stacksys} {m}
    {
        \ss_make_table:n {#1}
        \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1}{\l_ss_num_rows_int}
            {
                \tl_put_right:cn {l_row_{##1}_tl}{\\}
            }
        \begin{array}{*{\int_use:N \l_ss_num_cols_int}{c}}
        \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1}{\l_ss_num_rows_int}
            {
                \tl_use:c {l_row_{##1}_tl}
            }
        \end{array}
        \bool_gset_false:N \l_has_run_bool
    }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ss_make_table:n #1
    {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;} {#1}
        \int_set:Nn \l_ss_num_cols_int {\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq}
        \seq_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_seq \ss_process_cols:n
    }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ss_process_cols:n #1
    {
        \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq {,} {#1}
        \int_set:Nn \l_ss_num_rows_int {\seq_count:N \l_tmpb_seq}
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpb_seq
            {
                \bool_if:NTF \l_has_run_bool
                    {
                      \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
                      \tl_put_right:cn {l_row_{\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}_tl} {&##1}
                    }
                    {
                      \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
                      \tl_clear_new:c {l_row_{\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}_tl}
                      \tl_put_right:cn {l_row_{\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}_tl} {##1}
                    }
            }
        \bool_gset_true:N \l_has_run_bool
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\[
\stacksys{,r1,r2;c1,1,2;c2,3,4;c3,5,6}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm adjusting it now to my specific situation (and taking care of 100 other tasks).  Once I've got it working, I'll accept.  Your use of :c is so simple and clear, thanks!  [current project is detecting the last row, since somehow I'm getting an extra visible row when using {r|rrr} style tabular headings]

Comment: Officially, the colon is supposed to work in `\seq_set_split:Nnn` right? I agree it doesn't, and I couldn't make it work. The hyphen looks fine, so this is only for curiosity.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, I thought that it "should" work (I couldn't find it excluded in the documentation), but was getting errors so I changed it to the "-".  You can switch that to something else if you like.

Comment: @ScottH. A few 'LaTeX3 Best Practice' comments. I'd encourage you to pick a single prefix here, both for functions and variables (namespace management is important!): perhaps `tabtran`? Most of your stuff is not expandable, so `\cs_new_protected:Npn` would be better than `\cs_new:Npn`. In 'integer expression' contexts you don't need `\int_use:N` as TeX automatically does this, so we tend to leave them out.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the suggestions.  I've been trying to remember to add a unique prefix, but forgot this time!  For the second I'll have to read up on `protected` as I don't really understand when it is required.  I interpret the third as meaning that if an integer expression is expected, then the `\int_use:N` is unnecessary because `\int_eval` is applied anyway?

Comment: @ScottH. If your function uses _any_ material from `interface3` and there is _no star_ in the docs, you should use `protected`. The most common case is that anything which performs an assignment (setting a variable) must be `protected`. AS you say, integer expressions all carry out the equivalent of `\int_eval:n` internally.

Comment: @ScottH. Thanks!  If you want to only give the bottom answer, that is fine with me. I ended up changing the syntax a little (and using tl_head). I think your second answer will help more people. :-)

Comment: Oh, but one thing I had to fix that might not be obvious: if you use the command twice, terrible things happen.  You just need to zero out the global variables at the beginning, so an easy fix.

Comment: Oops, my bad...forgot to clear things.  If you're ok with the second answer I'll just get rid of the first as it's a bit more sloppy and a bit less general.  Glad it works for you.

Comment: It's not worth an edit but `\bool_gset_false` on line 21 can be deleted if `\bool_gset_true` on line 49 is changed to `\bool_set_true`