# Reflect / flip / rotate a table or array without rotating the elements

Tags: tables, rotating, arrays, reflection

I have been working on an `array` environment, but I have realized that it would take up less space if it was reflected across the diagonal (I suppose this is not quite the same as flipped or rotated, but I thought I would include those keywords for similarity). This realization has come too late, because it will take me a long time to rewrite everything in the reflected manner. I was wondering, is there a quick fix to my laziness? I would like a way to reflect the array below without rotating any of the elements. That is, I would like `x_1`,...,`x_8` across the top from left to right in the first row, `b_{1,1}`,...,`b_{8,1}` across the second row from left to right, and so on. Rotated would be `x_8`,...,`x_1` across from left to right, and I guess that would be an okay solution (though I would like the reflected one better).

I tried `rotatebox`, `adjustbox`, and `sidewaystable`, but all those also rotate the elements. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand\squared[1]{\noindent\framebox{\bf{#1}}}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand*\triangled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw,inner sep=0pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

$
\begin{array}{c|c c c c c c c c c}
x_1 & \squared{$b_{1,1}$} & \circled{$b_{1,2}$} & b_{1,3} & b_{1,4} & b_{1,5} & b_{1,6} & b_{1,7} & b_{1,8} & \cdots \\
x_2 & b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & b_{2,3} & b_{2,4} & b_{2,5} & b_{2,6} & b_{2,7} & b_{2,8} & \cdots \\
x_3 & \squared{$b_{3,1}$} & \circled{$b_{3,2}$} & \triangled{$b_{3,3}$} & b_{3,4} & b_{3,5} & b_{3,6} & b_{3,7} & b_{3,8} & \cdots \\
x_4 & \squared{$b_{4,1}$} & b_{4,2} & b_{4,3} & b_{4,4} & b_{4,5} & b_{4,6} & b_{4,7} & b_{4,8} & \cdots \\
x_5 & b_{5,1} & b_{5,2} & b_{5,3} & b_{5,4} & b_{5,5} & b_{5,6} & b_{5,7} & b_{5,8} & \cdots \\
x_6 & \squared{$b_{6,1}$} & b_{6,2} & b_{6,3} & b_{6,4} & b_{6,5} & b_{6,6} & b_{6,7} & b_{6,8} & \cdots \\
x_7 & \squared{$b_{7,1}$} & \circled{$b_{7,2}$} & \triangled{$b_{7,3}$} & b_{7,4} & b_{7,5} & b_{7,6} & b_{7,7} & b_{7,8} & \cdots \\
x_8 & \squared{$b_{8,1}$} & \circled{$b_{8,2}$} & b_{8,3} & b_{8,4} & b_{8,5} & b_{8,6} & b_{8,7} & b_{8,8} & \cdots \\
\vdots & 
\end{array}
$

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might want to check out some of the solutions posted in response to this earlier question: [tabular input by columns (i.e. transpose a table)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75793/22413)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that's a bit different from those that I linked to.  You will probably want to tweak this a bit to get it to produce what you want:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand\squared[1]{\noindent\framebox{\bf{#1}}}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand*\triangled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw,inner sep=0pt] (char) {#1};}}

%-@-(1)------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter

\def\ae@transposed@array{}

\NewEnviron{tarray}[1]
  {\let\ae@transposed@array\relax
   \def\ae@column@max{0}%%
   \expandafter\ae@build@array\BODY\\\@nil
   \def\ae@column@cnt{0}%%
   \ae@assemble@array
   \edef\ae@transposed@array{%%
     \noexpand\begin{array}{#1}
        \expandonce\ae@transposed@array
      \noexpand\end{array}}%%
  \typeout{====>\detokenize\expandafter{\ae@transposed@array}}%%
   \ae@transposed@array 
  }

\def\ae@build@array#1\\#2\@nil{%%
  %\typeout{==> row --> NUM1:\detokenize{#1}}%%
  %\typeout{==> row --> NUM2:\detokenize{#2}}%%
  \def\ae@continue@array{}%%
  \def\ae@column@cnt{0}%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \ae@parse@row@into@columns#1&\@nil
  \else
    \ae@parse@row@into@columns#1&\@nil
    %\typeout{@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@}%%
    \def\ae@continue@array{\ae@build@array#2\@nil}%%
  \fi
  %\typeout{====> columns:\ae@column@cnt:\ae@column@max}%%
  \ae@continue@array
}

\def\ae@parse@row@into@columns#1&#2\@nil{%%
  \def\ae@continue@row{}%%
  \edef\ae@column@cnt{\number\numexpr\ae@column@cnt+1\relax}%%
  \ifnum\ae@column@cnt>\ae@column@max\relax
    \edef\ae@column@max{\ae@column@cnt}%%%
  \fi
  %\typeout{==> row ==> \ae@column@cnt ==> \detokenize{#1}}%%
  %\typeout{==> row ==> \ae@column@cnt ==> \detokenize{#2}}%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
  \else
    \@ifundefined{ae@row@\ae@column@cnt}
      {\def\ae@tmp{#1}%%
       \expandafter\edef\csname ae@row@\ae@column@cnt\endcsname{\expandonce\ae@tmp}}%%
      {\def\ae@tmp{#1}%%
       \expandafter\edef\csname ae@row@\ae@column@cnt\endcsname{\expandafter\expandonce\csname ae@row@\ae@column@cnt\endcsname&\expandonce\ae@tmp}}
    \def\ae@continue@row{\ae@parse@row@into@columns#2\@nil}%%
    %\typeout{-----------------------------------}%%
  \fi
  \ae@continue@row
}

\def\ae@assemble@array{%%
  \def\ae@continue{}%%
  \ifnum\ae@column@cnt<\ae@column@max\relax
    \typeout{==:\ae@column@cnt:}%%
    \edef\ae@column@cnt{\number\numexpr\ae@column@cnt+1\relax}%%
    \typeout{==:\ae@column@cnt:}%%
    \@ifundefined{ae@transposed@array}
      {\edef\ae@transposed@array{\expandafter\expandonce\csname ae@row@\ae@column@cnt\endcsname\noexpand\\}}%%
      {\edef\ae@transposed@array{\expandonce\ae@transposed@array\expandafter\expandonce\csname ae@row@\ae@column@cnt\endcsname\noexpand\\}}
    \def\ae@continue{\ae@assemble@array}%%
  \fi
  \typeout{==> \ae@column@cnt}%%
  \ae@continue
}


\makeatother
%-@-(2)------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

$
\begin{tarray}{c|c c c c c c c c c}
x_1    & \squared{$b_{1,1}$} & \circled{$b_{1,2}$} & b_{1,3}               & b_{1,4} & b_{1,5} & b_{1,6} & b_{1,7} & b_{1,8} & \cdots \\
x_2    & b_{2,1}             & b_{2,2}             & b_{2,3}               & b_{2,4} & b_{2,5} & b_{2,6} & b_{2,7} & b_{2,8} & \cdots \\
x_3    & \squared{$b_{3,1}$} & \circled{$b_{3,2}$} & \triangled{$b_{3,3}$} & b_{3,4} & b_{3,5} & b_{3,6} & b_{3,7} & b_{3,8} & \cdots \\
x_4    & \squared{$b_{4,1}$} & b_{4,2}             & b_{4,3}               & b_{4,4} & b_{4,5} & b_{4,6} & b_{4,7} & b_{4,8} & \cdots \\
x_5    & b_{5,1}             & b_{5,2}             & b_{5,3}               & b_{5,4} & b_{5,5} & b_{5,6} & b_{5,7} & b_{5,8} & \cdots \\
x_6    & \squared{$b_{6,1}$} & b_{6,2}             & b_{6,3}               & b_{6,4} & b_{6,5} & b_{6,6} & b_{6,7} & b_{6,8} & \cdots \\
x_7    & \squared{$b_{7,1}$} & \circled{$b_{7,2}$} & \triangled{$b_{7,3}$} & b_{7,4} & b_{7,5} & b_{7,6} & b_{7,7} & b_{7,8} & \cdots \\
x_8    & \squared{$b_{8,1}$} & \circled{$b_{8,2}$} & b_{8,3}               & b_{8,4} & b_{8,5} & b_{8,6} & b_{8,7} & b_{8,8} & \cdots \\
\vdots & 
\end{tarray}
$

\end{document}
```

A couple of comments are probably in order:

The primary idea here is to parse the table based upon rows ending in `\\` and column entries separated by `&` and rebuild the table so that rows and columns are transposed.

There are two primary macros:  the first is `\ae@build@array` which peels away each row and sends the row to the macro `\ae@parse@row@into@columns`.  I use *pseudo* counters (so as not to clutter up counter registers---don't know whether I should really be worried about this) to keep track of the row the current *column* is being added to.

Having parsed the entire table, I reassemble the new table.  It just so happens that you have as many rows and columns, but the first argument should be formatting for each column of the *transposed* table.  (I think this makes this philosophically different from those of the linked question.)

Getting rules into the table is probably a bit more tricky.  For now, I'll leave the headache unsolved.

I've left in the `\typeout` macros I used to help me track what I was doing when assembling the table.  That way you can see a bit better (if you so desire) how the assembly is progressing (particularly if you try tweaking and things break on you).

I unabashedly use the resources of `etoolbox`.  You might want to check whether there are any *counterindications* against other packages:  I don't know of any off the top of my head.  I also use the `environ` package which makes it particularly easy to pass the contents of the table to a macro for parsing and restyling.  (Once again you might want to check for conflicts with other packages you may be using.)