# How to easily write the transpose of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix A, described using an environment *bmatrix* as in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Consider the matrix 
$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -1 \\ 
2 & 3 & 1  \\  
\end{bmatrix}$

Then its transpose is 
$A^T=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
0 & 3\\ 
-1 & 1  \\  
\end{bmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

How can I get the transpose of A without typing all its entries? In other word, is there an environment where \ means "end of column" instead of "end of row"?

I hope I could just paste and copy the definition of A and then change bmatrix to *vbmatrix* or whatever.

Comment: there is this, but I wouldn't use it, better to just get your editor to transpose http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75793/tabular-input-by-columns-i-e-transpose-a-table/75799#75799

Comment: You can find it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283081/124842. There are 2 possible answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to save the matrix in some unique name, then to reuse this matrix while rotating it at the same time.

Note that (see why [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/problem-with-defining-shortcuts-for-tikz-matrices)) you can not use a simple ampersand as a separator when using a command to typeset matrices with tikz.

Note also that the last \\ is mandatory (otherwise you will get a missing } error).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand{\mycustommatrix}[2]{
  \global\expandafter\def\csname mycustommatrixnamed#1\endcsname{#2}
  \left [ \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
    \matrix[matrix of math nodes, ampersand replacement=\&] { \csname mycustommatrixnamed#1\endcsname };
  \end{tikzpicture} \right ]
}

\newcommand{\mycustomtranspose}[1]{
  \left [ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\reflectbox{ \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
    \matrix[matrix of math nodes, ampersand replacement=\&, nodes={rotate=90,xscale=-1}] { \csname mycustommatrixnamed#1\endcsname };
  \end{tikzpicture} }} \right ]
}

\begin{document}

$A = \mycustommatrix{A}{
  1 \& 0 \& -1 \\
  2 \& 3 \& 1 \\
}$

$A^T = \mycustomtranspose{A}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]