# Is it possible to exchange rows and columns of a table without retyping

Tags: tables

I wrote a table that turned out to be too wide. So I have to turn it sideways for it to fit a typical journal paper. Is there a way I can avoid typing it all over again?!

Comment: Do you mean you want to rotate the whole table or that you want to make all the rows into columns (like transpose in Excel)?

Comment: @Thruston I want to transpose the matrix.

Comment: pgfplotstable can create a transpose.  On page 4 it shows how to fake a tabular environment.  On page 62 it shows how to transpose.

Comment: If you use Emacs’ org-mode to prepare your tables, org-mode can transpose tables: http://pragmaticemacs.com/emacs/transpose-a-table-in-org-mode/

Comment: See if this could be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283081/101651

Comment: I wrote [a TeX-aware table filter](https://github.com/thruston/perl-vim-table) for use with Vim that does table transposition:  select the rows and do "Table xp" for a transpose.  If you post your table here, I could post a transposed version as an answer.

Comment: @Thruston Thanks, I ended up typing it again and editing it quite a bit to make it smaller. But It is good to know these options are available for a large table.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75793 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like John Kormylo said, [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplotstable.pdf) can be a convenient way to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
{Header 1}   A   B   C   D   E
{Header 2}   1   2   3   4   5
{Header 3}  10   11   12   13   14
}\tablesource

\pgfplotstabletranspose[string type,
                        colnames from={Header 1},
                        input colnames to={Header 1}
                        ]\tabletransp{\tablesource}

\begin{center}
Table Source:

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
        every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        after row=\midrule
]{\tablesource}
\vspace{8mm}

Table transpose:

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
        every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        after row=\midrule
]{\tabletransp}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I'm not a expert, but in my test's I understand that's need to stay alert about spaces.

In `\pgfplotstableread` you will enter you source table. Into the final of this command, you will name this source; in this case is `\tablesource`.

In `\pgfplotstabletranspose` you will finish with tha name of transposed table; `\tabletransp`.

The command `\pgfplotstabletypeset` will call what you put into brackets.

[image: Source and Transpose tables with pgfplotstabletranspose]