# Transposing regression table in latex

Tags: tables, multicolumn, overleaf, dcolumn

I have a regression table in latex that is the result of output from applying the stargazer package on my regression results in R. I am wondering how to transpose the table such that the columns switch place with rows. In other words, I want the Lags to be where the variables are and vice versa.

Moreover, I am wondering how to reduce the space between the first and second columns as well as how to add a vertical line between columns. I've tried adding | in between, but sometimes this doesn't cover well and leaves in some space in between the top and bottom hline.

```
 \usepackage{dcolumn}
 \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Regression results} 
  \label{} 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{lD{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2}} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Characteristics} \\ 
\cline{2-7} 
 \\ 
 Lags: & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Variable 1 & -1.14^{***} & 0.04 & -1.73^{***} & -0.24 & -0.59 & -1.64^{***} \\ 
  Variable 2 & 0.16 & -0.25 & 0.12 & -0.12 & 0.14{**} & 0.04  \\ 
  Variable 3 & 0.46^{*} & -0.61 & 0.17 & -0.98^{***} & -0.32 & -0.09\\ 
  Variable 4 & -0.02 & -0.005 & -0.03^{***} & -0.32 & -0.11 & 0.015 \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{6}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

[image: Code result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you aware that your code is not compilable? You can not have a `\multicolumn{18}` in a table that has only 7 columns. To get rid of the error message and simultaneously solve issue 2, you can use `\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textit{Note:} $^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} `.

Comment: Hi @leandriis, thx for your comment. This compiles in my overleaf because this example is just something I put together from an already existing table with 18 columns so I missed that adjustment!

Comment: `\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{7}` will still give you an error message since this adds up to 8 columns. Either place the "Note"  inside the multicolumn as well or use `\multicolumn{6}`

Comment: The vertical line nor working well with your table is due to the use of `\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] ` for the horizontal lines above the table. Insetad of that, I would use `\toprule` from the `booktabs` package. (However, the `booktabs` lines are incompatible with vertical lines, thus, I would not use a vertical line at all.)

Comment: Regarding transposing the table: Is there a special reason why you want to do that? Since the table is already narrower than the textwidth and thus fits into the available space perfectly fine, I don't think you can save space by transposing the table.

Comment: @leandriis Yes, my original table has 18 columns and only 6-7 variables. Therefore it seems better to have the table transposed. I just shortened the code and table for the purpose of asking the question. I already have horizontal tables with 18 columns where i flipped the PDF page, but I want vertical for this table as it shows something different than the others and I would like this to be clearer in my paper by having the table differently.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I assume you want to automatically transpose the table. Probably the answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75793/134144 could help with that.

Comment: I've already read those suggested solutions, but have a problem applying it to my code. E.g the pgfplotstable suggestion didn't do anything for me, so I must have done something wrong. (I am just getting started with Latex, have no previous experience).

Comment: To be honest, I would try to save the contents of the table as a csv file and use excel to transpose it. You will nevertheless have to do some adjustments to the code to get a decent result.

Comment: isn't it easy to transpose the data in R ?

Comment: No, for some reason the flip argument doesn't work with stargazer in R. Might be other ways around it, but not that I'm familiar with.

Comment: @Andycode If flip argument of stargazer doesn't work, before transpose your `x` matrix/data.frame of results with  `y <- t(x)` and then export `y` to a latex table with stargazer, or xtable, or kable. If you add  to the question a R  code making a matrix/dataframe  and the code that you use to produce the latex table, we could help from this point, ideally without having to touch up the R output.