# Specifying an array columnwise in math mode

Tags: tables, math-mode, boxes

I would like to do the same sort of thing as in the question [How to create table column wise in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346711/how-to-create-table-column-wise-in-latex), except that I want to do it in math mode.

To be precise: I want to enter an array of items of possibly different sizes, similar to the `matrix` environment, except that in the LaTeX source code I want to specify one column of items and the next column, and so on, instead of specifying the items by row as usual. I want the result to be vertically centered like the `matrix` environment.

I also want to be able to specify the amount of horizontal and vertical space between the items.

Here is an mwe to show what I mean.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    x = 
    \begin{matrix}
        1 & 4 \\
        2 & 5 \\
        3 & \Big(6\Big) \\
    \end{matrix} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

In this LaTeX code, the items appear in the order 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, but I want to specify them in the order 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

(Actually, even better than that would be 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4 - column-wise but with the columns specified in reverse order. But I can imagine this being difficult and will be happy enough with the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 order.)

Here's what the mwe output looks like.

[image]

There is a related question, [Is there a way to automatically transpose a matrix written in Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283081/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-transpose-a-matrix-written-in-latex), but because that question is asking specifically about transposing a matrix, the answers don't end up having a way to specify the space between elements. I'm hoping for a simpler solution along the lines of the top answer at [How to create table column wise in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346711/how-to-create-table-column-wise-in-latex), which is more about stacking boxes  on top of each other than doing hefty expl3 stuff.

Comment: I know no way to make that automagically, but you can type your matrix content  with three columns and two rows.

Comment: You seems to be familiar with Python, so just use PythonTeX to implement a macro to do that. Should be easy right

Comment: @user202729 right, it's completely straightforward in PythonTeX, but I'm looking for a pure LaTeX solution because PythonTeX has compatibility issues with Overleaf and also with arXiv.

Comment: it's easy to arrange a macro that specifies  2x6 matrix in any order, a bit harder to to the general case

Comment: @F.Pantigny that's linked in my question already.

Comment: Although I hadn't seen @wipet's valign answer to that previous question, which is useful.

Answer (score 1):

`\valign` primitive was designed for such a task:

```
\def\iskip{\vskip2pt plus1fil}
$$
  x = 
  \vcenter{\hbox{\valign{&\iskip\hbox to1.5em{\hss$#$\hss}\iskip\cr
     1 & 2 & 3 \cr
     4 & 5 & (6) \cr
  }}}
$$

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even use the proposed syntax (bottom up):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\rmatrix}{O{2}m}
 {% #1 is the number of columns, default 2
  % #2 is a comma separated list of items
  \virgo_rmatrix:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__virgo_rmatrix_items_seq
\tl_new:N \l__virgo_rmatrix_body_tl
\int_new:N \l__virgo_rmatrix_rows_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \virgo_rmatrix:nn
 {
  % this will contain the body
  \tl_clear:N \l__virgo_rmatrix_body_tl
  % make a sequence from the items
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__virgo_rmatrix_items_seq { #2 }
  % check if the number of items is a multiple of #1
  \int_compare:nF
   {
    \int_mod:nn { \seq_count:N \l__virgo_rmatrix_items_seq } { #1 } == 0
   }
   {% not a multiple, pad
    \prg_replicate:nn
     { #1 - \int_mod:nn { \seq_count:N \l__virgo_rmatrix_items_seq } { #1 } }
     { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__virgo_rmatrix_items_seq { } }
   }
  % determine the number of rows
  \int_set:Nn \l__virgo_rmatrix_rows_int
   {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { \seq_count:N \l__virgo_rmatrix_items_seq } { #1 }
   }
  % read the items
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { \l__virgo_rmatrix_rows_int } { -1 } { 1 }
   {% ##1 is the row index
    \int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { #1 - 1 }
     {% ####1 is the column index minus 1
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__virgo_rmatrix_body_tl
       {
        \seq_item:Nn \l__virgo_rmatrix_items_seq { ##1 + ####1*\l__virgo_rmatrix_rows_int }
        \int_compare:nTF { ####1 = #1 - 1 } { \exp_not:N \\ } { & }
       }
     }
   }
   \begin{matrix}
   \tl_use:N \l__virgo_rmatrix_body_tl
   \end{matrix}
 }

\begin{document}

\[
x=
\rmatrix{3,2,1,\bigl(6\bigr),5,4}
\]

\[
x=
\rmatrix[3]{3,2,1,\bigl(6\bigr),5,4}
\]

\[
x=
\rmatrix[4]{3,2,1,\bigl(6\bigr),5,4,9,8,7,10}
\]

\end{document}
```

The number of items is made a multiple of the number of columns, the number of rows is computed by that data.

The sequence is then traversed from every multiple of the number of rows backwards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an imperfect self-answer, essentially formed by wrapping the answer to [How to create table column wise in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346711/how-to-create-table-column-wise-in-latex) in `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`.

It's imperfect because I'm just hacking away at the other answer without really understanding how it works, and also because it doesn't come out perfectly vertically centred - there must be some subtlety about `\vecenter` that I'm not understanding. Additionally the elements are not centred within their columns, though that's not a huge issue for me.

But on the plus side it behaves how I wanted in that the array is specified columnwise in the source, and in that it offers the desired control over spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{colarray}[2]{%
\vcenter\bgroup\hbox\bgroup\valign\bgroup&\vfil\vbox{\parindent=0pt\tabskip=#2\hsize=#1##}\vfil\cr}%
{\egroup\egroup\egroup}
\newcommand*\col[1]{#1\cr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    x = \begin{colarray}{4mm}{2mm}
        \col{1 & 2 & 3}
        \col{4 & 5 & \Big(6\Big)}
    \end{colarray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

update: I figured out the vertical spacing issue. There needs to be a negative vskip to cancel out the tabskip on the last row. Unfortunately that means it has to be a newcommand and not a newenvironment, but here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% this can't be an environment because the code for \end can't have parameters.
\newcommand{\colarray}[3]{
\vcenter{\hbox{\valign{&\vfil\vbox{\parindent=0pt\tabskip=#2\hsize=#1##}\vfil\cr%
#3%
}}\vskip-#2}%
}

\newcommand*\col[1]{#1\cr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    x = \colarray{4mm}{2mm}{
        \col{1 & 2 & 3}
        \col{4 & 5 & \Big(6\Big)}
    }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now it's just the horizontal centering within cells that I need to figure out.

Comment: Talk about the "understanding" part if you really want to, start with the TeXbook. (not free though. There's TeX by Topic but covers the primitives only)

Comment: @user202729 I read it once (or part of it at least), when I was a student and had time on my hands. But that was well over a decade ago and I can't remember any of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but too long for a comment. Hopefully it can be useful for somebody, perhaps somebody can cook up a solution for lualatex?

In ConTeXt there has for a while been possible to transpose matrices. We can define a matrix type that is transposed (done in lua) as

```
\definemathmatrix[virgomatrix][
    action=transpose,
    simplecommand=virgomatrix,
    distance=4em,
]
```

Once that is done we can add a transposed matrix with

```
\dm{ x = \virgomatrix{1,2,3; 4,5,\Bigl( 6 \Bigr); 7,8} }
```

Output:
[image: Transposed matrix]

If we also want to change the order of the rows we need to have a look at `math-ali.lmt` where this is defined. There we find

```
local actions = {
    transpose = function(m)
        local t = { }
        for j=1,#m[1] do
            local r = { }
            for i=1,#m do
                r[i] = m[i][j]
            end
            t[j] = r
        end
        return t
    end,
...
}
```

where the three dots is just indicating that some parts are being left out.

We can imitate this and define our own "Virgo" action (note the small change in `r[i]`).

```
\startluacode
    mathematics.registersimplematrix("Virgo",function(m)
        local t = { }
        for j=1,#m[1] do
            local r = { }
            for i=1,#m do
                r[i] = m[i][#m[1]-j+1]
            end
            t[j] = r
        end
        return t
    end)
\stopluacode
```

Then we can use it. We define a new type of matrix, the `Virgo` matrix.

```
\definemathmatrix[Virgomatrix][
    action={Virgo},
    simplecommand=Virgomatrix,
    distance=4em,
]
```

We then use this new type:

```
\dm{ x = \Virgomatrix{1,2,3;4,5,\Bigl( 6 \Bigr);7,8} }
```

The output is shown below.
[image: a Virgo matrix]