# horizontal centering within \valign cells

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, plain-tex

I'm trying to use `\valign` to make an array of items. (See my [self-answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653445/12461).) I'm doing this because I want to specify the items per column instead of per row, and because I want control over the spacing. I'm using LaTeX but these are [plain-tex](/questions/tagged/plain-tex) macros.

I'm happy with the following, except that the items are not vertically centred within their column, so this question is about how to achieve that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% this can't be an environment because the code for \end can't have parameters.
\newcommand{\colarray}[3]{
\vcenter{\hbox{\valign{&\vfil\vbox{\parindent=0pt\tabskip=#2\hsize=#1##}\vfil\cr%
#3%
}}\vskip-#2}%
}

\newcommand*\col[1]{#1\cr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    x = \colarray{4mm}{2mm}{
        \col{1 & 2 & 3}
        \col{4 & 5 & \Big(6\Big)}
    }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

From my current rather hazy understanding, centering the items should involve putting each one in an `\hbox` and using `\vfil`. However, if I try that the results are not as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% this can't be an environment because the code for \end can't have parameters.
\newcommand{\colarray}[3]{
\vcenter{\hbox{\valign{&\vfil\vbox{\parindent=0pt\tabskip=#2\hsize=#1\hbox to #1{\hfil##\hfil}}\vfil\cr%
#3%
}}\vskip-#2}%
}

\newcommand*\col[1]{#1\cr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    x = \colarray{4mm}{2mm}{
        \col{1 & 2 & 3}
        \col{4 & 5 & \Big(6\Big)}
    }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

As you can see the '3' is horizontally aligned differently from the '1' and '2', and the '(6)' is not horizontally centred with respect to the '4' and '5'.

I am not able to work out why this is, so my questions are (1) why is this happening, and (2) how can I fix it?

Comment: When you use `\valign`, you give up the common baseline that `\halign` would give you. To compensate for that, you can make all vboxes in your alignment the same height and insert a "strut" to control the baseline. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621056/255231) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the spaces before each `&` in your usage of `\colarray`, as they are significant when they get substituted in the inner `\hbox`. Alternatively, replace `##` with `$##$` in the definition of `\colarray`. Also, I don't think 4mm is big enough for the parenthesized "6"; to align the columns, you will need to increase it.

By the way, you do not need to set `\parindent` and `\hsize` in your second attempted solution.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is similar to RobertR's suggestions, but as a full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% this can't be an environment because the code for \end can't have parameters.
% ?? It would be more natural as an environment with \\ like array
\newcommand{\colarray}[3]{%
\vcenter{\hbox{\valign{&\vfil\tabskip=#2\hbox to #1{\strut\hfil$##$\hfil}\vfil\cr%
#3%
}}\vskip-#2}}

\newcommand*\col[1]{#1\cr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    x = \colarray{5mm}{2mm}{
        \col{1 & 2 & 3}
        \col{4 & 5 & \Bigl(6\Bigr)}
    }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```